# How to get a Port to listen on Windows 7?

Tags: command-line, port, tcpip

I have followed the [step by step instruction to open a port](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall) on Windows 7, setting both **Inbound Rules** and **Outbound Rules** to following specification:

```
Protocal Type: TCP
Local Port: 55000
Remote Port: 55001
Scope: Any IP address
Programs: All programs that meet the specified conditions
Profiles: Domain, Private, Public (all checked)
Name: FooPort
```

[image: ScreenShot1][image: ScreenShot2]

Then I run `netstat -a` on my command prompt to find the open port, the TCP port 55000 or 55001 aren't there as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

If I try telnet myself, I, of course, receive the following error:

[image: telnet Screenshot1]

How can I open the port and get it to listen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you open up a Shop Checkout, you need to put a Cashier behind it such that people can pass with their products. If you only have tho Shop Checkout open, nothing can pass if there's nobody there.

So, besides opening the port you need an application that listens to that port.

The port itself, however, can only be open. Ports can't listen by themselves... Applications listen.

Comment: +1 and correct. I just wrote a piece of code to instantiate a TcpListener (C#). Now it's listening and showing on netstat.

Answer (score 1):

As Tom Wijsman says, you need an application to listen.

[Port Listener](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/portlistener/) is a free lightweight utility to listen on a specified port.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a telnet daemon configured for listening on that port.  ;-)))
(if you want to test it with telnet)